# OpenGL how to implement free moving camera?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, perspectivecamera

I am trying to implement a basic free moving camera in OpenGL. 
I want to understand the operations so I'm not using gluLookAt. 
I've tried a few things but it doesn't work as expected.

This is my render

```
// Every frame
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, 0, 40); 

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); 

// camera transforms:
glTranslatef(eye_x, eye_y, eye_z);
glRotatef(x_angular, 0, 1, 0); 

// foreach object:
glPushMatrix();
{
    glTranslatef( (*obj_i)->anchor[0] , (*obj_i)->anchor[1], (*obj_i)->anchor[2]);
    glutWireSphere((*obj_i)->r, 15, 15);
}
glPopMatrix();
```

And my input processing

```
        // VK_UP
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 129  ) {
            buffer << " Key press: VK_UP \n";
            eye_z += 1;
        }
        // VK_DOWN
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 131  ) {
            buffer << " Key press: VK_DOWN \n";
            eye_z -= 1;
        }
        // VK_LEFT
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 128  ) {
            //eye_x += 10;
            buffer << " Key press: VK_LEFT \n";

            x_angular -= 2;
            //glRotatef(x_angular, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        // VK_RIGHT
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 130  ) {
            //eye_x -= 10;
            buffer << " Key press: VK_RIGHT \n";

            x_angular += 2;

        }
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 'i' ) {

        }
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 'j' ) {
            eye_x += 10;
        }
        else if ( (*event_it)->key == 'k' ) {
            eye_x -= 10;
        }
```

What I am trying to do:
There are 3 spheres at z=0, I want to go in (pass them) and then VK_LEFT (turn left) do a 180 and then I should be able to see the spheres.

Not quite sure what's wrong, maybe my input processing is wrong, or the operations are off?

With glOrtho(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, 0, 40) 
z_near is 0 and z_far = 40 right? 
if I draw at z=0 and glTranslate(0,0,-10) I would approach the z_far ? And pass what was drawn at z=0 ?

I've read lots of q/a and tutorials but I can't connect the explanation with my code.

Edit
This looks closer to what I want. Will need to run more tests, I think there might still be a glitch or two.

```
    glTranslatef(windowWidth/2.0, windowHeight/2.0,-1);
    glRotatef(x_angular, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(-windowWidth/2.0,-windowHeight/2.0,1);

    glTranslatef(eye_x, eye_y, eye_z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Translation and Rotation in OpenGL are performed using Matrix multiplication. In the fixed function pipeline that you are using, these operations are not commutative i.e. [T]x[R] is not equal to [R]x[T]. In your code you are translating first which changes the origin for the rotation that comes next.

If you look closely at how the gluLookAt() is implemented. The camera translation needs to be inverted. remember the translation and rotation will be applied to the objects. There is no such thing as a camera in OpenGL. We simply simulate it by applying the inverse of camera transformations to the scene.

The only way you will understand this is by learning the math behind OpenGL. I would suggest finding a book.

Try the code below. Remember we are simulating the camera, so use glTranslate and glRotate to do the inverse.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// camera transforms:
glTranslatef(-eye_x, -eye_y, -eye_z);
glRotatef(-x_angular, 0, 1, 0); 

// foreach object:
glPushMatrix();
{
    glTranslatef( (*obj_i)->anchor[0] , (*obj_i)->anchor[1], (*obj_i)-    >anchor[2]);
    glutWireSphere((*obj_i)->r, 15, 15);
}
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: @Lazik Edited the code snippet. I forgot that the fixed function pipeline matrix multiplication is done bottom-up. anyways if you are indeed drawing your spheres at (0,0,0) setting the camera at (0, 0, -10) will work. which is the same as doing a `glTranslatef( 0, 0, 10 )` on the entire scene.

Comment: This is already what I had. The values are inverted in the input processing. My projection matrix is glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, z_near, z_far) so I believe there is something to be done with centering in the middle of the screen before the rotation, see my edit.